# CublasAPI failed with status 15 - Google Flan T5 XL Model Inference

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to use the Google FLAN-T5-XL model to run some inference at home, using the following code:

```
from transformers import T5Tokenizer, T5ForConditionalGeneration
from torch import no_grad
import time

modeldir="/home/text-generation-webui/models/"

tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained("google/flan-t5-xl", cache_dir=modeldir, device='cuda')
model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("google/flan-t5-xl", device_map="auto", cache_dir=modeldir, load_in_8bit=True)

with no_grad():
    while True:
        # Get user input
        user_input = input("Prompt: ")

        # start timer
        start = time.time()

        # Concatenate user input with initial prompt
        inputs = tokenizer(user_input, return_tensors="pt")
        input_ids = inputs.input_ids.to('cuda')
        # Generate text
        outputs = model.generate(input_ids, max_new_tokens=500)

        # Decode output
        generated_text = tokenizer.decode(outputs[0], skip_special_tokens=True)

        # stop timer and print time taken
        print(f"Generated in {time.time() - start:.2f} seconds")

        # Print generated text
        print(generated_text)
```

The code loads ok, but crashes when I try to generate an output with an error message I can't understand.

```
cuBLAS API failed with status 15
A: torch.Size([1, 2048]), B: torch.Size([2048, 2048]), C: (1, 2048); (lda, ldb, ldc): (c_int(32), c_int(65536), c_int(32)); (m, n, k): (c_int(1), c_int(2048), c_int(2048))
error detectedTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/test_flant5.py", line 20, in <module>
    outputs = model.generate(input_ids, max_new_tokens=500)
  File "/home/.conda/envs/test/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/autograd/grad_mode.py", line 27, in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/.conda/envs/test/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/generation/utils.py", line 1437, in generate
    return self.greedy_search(
  File "/home/.conda/envs/test/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/generation/utils.py", line 2248, in greedy_search
    outputs = self ...
  File "/home/.conda/envs/test/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bitsandbytes/functional.py", line 1410, in igemmlt
    raise Exception('cublasLt ran into an error!')
Exception: cublasLt ran into an error!
```

From what I gather the issue could be that the input ID I'm feeding to the generate function is not the right shape, but I have no idea.

Any clue?

I was expecting for the program to return a text output. Instead it's crashing.